# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test started failing in KitKat with IllegalStateException

Tags: android, testing

I have a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 that starts a FragmentActivity (from support library v4) and then causes it to display a DialogFragment (for a time picker).

I have just upgraded my Nexus 4 where I was running the tests to KitKat and now this test has started failing.

I start the activity with getActivity() and then call the method that displays the DialogFragment.

When I call the show() method on the DialogFragment class, I get this exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Anyone else seen this or got any ideas.

Comment: I'm seeing this while testing on a HTC Sensation XE. I've worked out from a stack trace that it is calling several methods which lead up to a call of onSaveInstanceState(), but I haven't yet worked out why. Several people have said that FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss() rather than FragmentTransaction.commit() will help, but I'm reluctant to change my code like that to aid in testing.

Comment: I see the same on HTC One... no idea how to fix that